# How to filter preloaded records by query

Tags: elixir, ecto, preload

I am listing a list of records (Packs).

Those Packs are linked to items through a many to many relation :

- pack has_many packitems
- item has_many packitems
- item has_many :packs, through: [:packitems, :pack]
- pack has_many :items, through: [:packitems, :item]

When I am listing the packs, i'd like to preload their **active** items

```
def list_packs(params) do
  packs = Pack
    |> preload_active_items()
    |> Repo.all()
    |> Repo.preload([:classroom, [packlanguages: :language]])
end

defp preload_active_items(query) do
  query
    |> join(:left, [pack], _ in assoc(pack, :packitems))
    |> join(:left, [_, pi], _ in assoc(pi, :item))
    |> where([..., i], i.active == true)
    |> preload([_, pi, i], [packitems: {pi, item: i}])
    # |> preload([_, pi, i], [packitems: {pi, item: ^from(i, where: i.active == true)}])
end
```

Everything is working fine (I retrieve the packs and their preloaded items), but I get the packs filtered on **those having an active item**.

I tried to replace the where clause by the dashed line but the syntax is not correct.

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you declare packitems as a has_many :through association?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I had these 2 rules ; I added on the post...

Answer (score 5):

I found my way finally :

```
def list_packs(params) do
  pi_query = from pi in PackItem,
    join: i in assoc(pi, :item),
    where: i.active == true
  packs = Pack
    |> Repo.all()
    |> Repo.preload([:classroom, [packlanguages: :language, packitems: pi_query]])
end
```